# Group by field name in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, grouping

I'm trying to group Java objects by their field, i.e *Person.java*

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    String surname;
    ....
}
```

So if I have *n* Person objects, what would be the easiest way to get all people name "David" into a map like `Map<String, List<Person>> map;`?

I found this on Google (but it doesn't compile), it seems to be the thing I'm looking for:
http://www.anzaan.com/2010/06/grouping-objects-using-objects-property/

Comment: what does the compile error say?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There's probably a library that can do this more simply, but it's not too hard to do it manually:

```
List<Person> allPeople; // your list of all people
Map<String, List<Person>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Person>>();
for (Person person : allPeople) {
   String key = person.getName();
   if (map.get(key) == null) {
      map.put(key, new ArrayList<Person>());
   }
   map.get(key).add(person);
}

List<Person> davids = map.get("David");
```

Comment: But the question was about a general solution, where you just specify the name of a class, so you would pass a persons:=List of Person, and "name" as the name of the field, and the function would do the rest. In the next case you pass a list of cars, and a fieldname "manufactor". In scala, you would just call persons.filter (p => p.name == "David") or group on the list.

Comment: poor Java people... they will never know the joys of LINQ :)

Comment: Unless they use Groovy (or Scala) and do the following with closures, which I assume is as simple as LINQ.  `def davids = allPeople.findAll { p -> p.name == 'David' }`

Comment: @lliaG, with Java 8 now they [can](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-applying-lambdas-to-java-collections/) :)

Answer (score 28):

Using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) with the [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) class and [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), you can do this:

```
Map<String, List<Person>> mapByName = 
    allPeople.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName));

List<Person> allDavids = mapByName.getOrDefault("David", Collections.emptyList());
```

Here I used `getOrDefault` so that you get an empty immutable list instead of a `null` reference if there is no "David" in the original list, but you can use `get` if you prefer to have a `null` value.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Is it possible not to use a getter, but directly use the field name?

Comment: @ZhangMeng Yes, in this case you would use the lambda `p -> p.name`, assuming you can access the `name` field.

Answer (score 11):

[Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s Multimap does exactly what you need and much more, avoiding much boilerplate code:

```
ListMultimap<String, Person> peopleByFirstName = ArrayListMultimap.create();
for (Person person : getAllPeople()) {
    peopleByFirstName.put(person.getName(), person);
}
```

Source: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap

Comment: A really helpful fact would be to tell people to call `asMap()` on the result.  `keys()`, `entries()` and `values()` does not seem to group as you'd expect it to.

Answer (score 4):

something like that (i didn't compile)

```
void addPerson(Person p, Map<String, List<Person>> map){
  ArrayList<Person> lst = map.get(p.name);
  if(lst == null){
     lst = new ArrayList<Person>();
  }
  lst.add(p);
  map.put(p.name, lst);
}
...
for(Person p:personsCollection>){
   addPerson(p, map);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, this is a feature of the class List already:

```
class Person (val name: String, val surname: String ="Smith") 
val li = List (new Person ("David"), new Person ("Joe"), new Person ("Sue"), new Person ("David", "Miller")) 
li.groupBy (_.name)
```

> res87:
>   scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Person]]
>   = Map((David,List(Person@1c3f810, Person@139ba37)),
>   (Sue,List(Person@11471c6)),
>   (Joe,List(Person@d320e4)))

Since Scala is bytecode compatible to Java, you should be able to call that method from Java, if you include the scala-jars.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Multimap](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/multimap/Multimap.html) and `groupBy()` from [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/)

```
MutableList<Person> allPeople = Lists.mutable.empty();
MutableListMultimap<String, Person> multimapByName = allPeople.groupBy(Person::getName);
```

If you can't change the type of allPeople from `List`

```
List<Person> allPeople = new ArrayList<>();
MutableListMultimap<String, Person> multimapByName = 
     ListAdapter.adapt(allPeople).groupBy(Person::getName);
```

Note: I am a contributor to Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should add objects of Person.java in the arraylist later we can get back those details in below manner

> public void addPerson(){
>
> ArrayList presonList = new ArrayList();
>
> for( int i=0;i<=presonList.size() ; i++){
>
> Person obj = presonList.get(i);
>
> //now do the stuff of getting individual variable here
>
> }
>
> }