# Group and sort ArrayLists based on names

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, grouping

Got stuck in the following problem. I populated a ArrayList from the database which is as below. But found that I need to group the list based on names (if the other two values in the first list match with second list) . And after grouping, I need to sort the names in ascending order. I am unable to find a solution to this. How should I iterate it, group and sort names?

VerDetail (0)

**Date :** Aug 3,2016
**Type :** Income
**Name :** Tom

VerDetail (1)

Aug 3,2016
SSN
Tom

VerDetail (2)

Aug 3,2016
Income
Ben

VerDetail (3)

Aug 3,2016
SSN
Ben

VerDetail (4)

Aug 3,2016
Income
Jack

VerDetail (5)

Aug 3,2016
SSN
Jack

I want my list to be grouped on names as below,

VerDetail (0)

Aug 3,2016
Income
Ben
Jack
Tom

VerDetail (1)

Aug 3,2016
SSN
Ben
Jack
Tom

Comment: Collections.sort will work

Comment: You can almost certainly do this with your SQL query (although, you haven't posted that so we can't really help you).

Comment: I am just getting a database object from another application and have no control on sorting it. Else I would have done that way.

Answer (score 0):

By using sort() method of collection, you can sort it by grouping.

```
public class SortTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(1);

        System.out.println("Unsorted: " + list);

        Collections.sort(list);

        System.out.println("Sorted: " + list);
    }

}
```

### Output:

```
Unsorted: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1] 
Sorted: [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Resource Link:** [How to group elements in ArrayList<CustomObject>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989020/how-to-group-elements-in-arraylistcustomobject)

---

### In Java 8

Using the Collectors class and streams, you can do this :

```
Map<String, List<Person>> mapByName = allPeople.stream()
                                               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName));
```

Resource Link: [Group by field name in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385066/group-by-field-name-in-java)